# Prevent cascade persist in @PrePersist

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

My entities are persisted in some generic way. For one of them I need to prevent the persist operation of `foo` collection(relation) if the `bar` member is set true. I've thought the `@PrePersist` method is a solution, but I cannot access EntityManager from there(to fetch and overwrite `foo` collection). Is there any other way to dynamically decide(from inside of entity) if a member should by persisted by a cascade?

Comment: using the cascade annotations is not an option?

Comment: I have `Cascade.ALL` already, but in some cases(`bar` is true) it should not be applied.